# How to delete everything after second column in notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I have 5000 lines of text like this:

Kenty:level 57:Elite:Knight:

Mawk:level 69:Elder:Druid:

Pog:level 122:Elite:Knight:

Tygger:level 34:Elder:Druid:

and i want it like this:

Kenty:level 57

Mawk:level 69

Pog:level 122

Tygger:level 34

Answer (score 1):

Using Regular Expression:

Replace all

`([^:]+:[^:]+):.*`

with

`\1`

Answer (score 0):

hey mate i dont think there is a way to do this in notepadd++ i would copy all the text you have then place it in excel then in the column next to it use this code `=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1)-14)` you may need to adjust the number `14` but it should be a quick fix for you. Then just copy the text info and paste it back in notepadd++